# diagnostic logs for mobile app with azure appcenter

Tags: visual-studio, azure, mobile, azureportal, visual-studio-app-center

I have account for azure portal and azure appcenter.
I had created the mobile app and integrated the azure appcenter sdk in that app.
Is there any way i can do diagnostic logs for the mobile app and send them to our server ?

I had notice that there is no good filteration option for filtering events or finding detail logs in appcenter.

how can i achieve that with azure portal?

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application insights is the tool for that.

Please take a look at [Start analyzing your mobile app with App Center and Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/mobile-center-quickstart#prerequisites).

By following the setup in the doc above, then you can use application insights to monitor / query logs / filter logs in azure portal.

Comment: Yes! This is correct. And once you link your Azure account and activate the App Insights functionality, Azure begins to export all the event data to a blob storage as you can see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/analytics/export and then you can get the data from there in multiple ways